# If $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ is càdlàg and $\tau_0:=0$, show that $\inf\left\{t>\tau_{n-1}:\Delta x(t)\in B\right\}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, continuity, stopping-times, levy-processes

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space and $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ be càdlàg with $x(0)=0$. Moreover, let $x(0-):=x(0)$, $$x(t-):=\lim_{s\to t-}x(s)\;\;\;\text{for }t>0$$ and $$\Delta x(t):=x(t)-x(t-)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0.$$

> Given $B\subseteq E$ bounded below, let $\tau_0:=0$ and $$\tau_n:=\inf\underbrace{\left\{t>\tau_{n-1}:\Delta x(t)\in B\right\}}_{=:\:I_n}$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.
>
> How can we show that $\tau_1>0$ and $\tau_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$?

I know that $\left|\left\{t\in[a,b]:\Delta x(t)\ne0\right\}\right|\in\mathbb N_0$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and hence $\left\{t\ge0:\Delta x(t)\ne0\right\}$ is countable. Does the claim somehow follow from this fact?

For example, if $\tau_1=0$, then we would find a nonincreasing $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq I_1$ with $t_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$. Is this a contradiction?

I know how we can prove a similar statement for any right-continuous $y:[0,\infty)\to E$. Assuming that $B$ is closed and $I:=\{t\ge0:y(t)\in B\}$ is nonempty, we can easily show that $\tau:=\inf I\in I$. Moreover, if $y(0)\not\in B$, we can show that $\tau>0$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by bounded below for a general normed space?

Comment: @K.Power $B$ is bounded below means that $r:=\inf_{x\in B}\|x\|_E>0$. Since $\Delta x(0)=0$, this would clearly yield $\tau_1>0$, if $t\mapsto\Delta x(t)$ would be continuous (which is clearly not the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know from [Show that if $x$ is càdlàg, $\left\{t\in[a,b]:d\left(x(t),x(t-)\right)>c\right\}$ is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4275867/42969) that for every $0 \le a < b$ the set
$$
 J(a, b) := \{t \in [a, b] :\Delta x(t)\in B \}
$$
is empty or finite.

Now assume that $\tau_0< \tau_1 < \cdots < \tau_n$ have already been defined. There are two possibilities:

- The set $I_n = \{ t > \tau_n :\Delta x(t)\in B \}$ is empty. In that case, $\tau_{n+1}$ can not be defined, and the construction is finished.
- The set $I_n$ is not empty, so that $\tau_{n+1} = \inf I_n$ is well-defined. Since $J(\tau_n, \tau_n + 1)$ is at most finite, $\tau_{n+1}$ must be strictly greater than $\tau_n$.

So the construction gives a finite or infinite sequence of strictly increasing $\tau_n$. If the construction does not stop after finitely many steps, then necessarily $\lim_{n \to \infty} \tau_n = \infty$:

Otherwise $\tau_n \to c$. For every $n$ is $\tau_{n+1} = \inf I_n < c$, so that there is a $t_n \in (\tau_n, c)$ with $\Delta x(t_n) \in B$. But then $J(0, c)$ contains infinitely many elements, which is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; got it now! However, just to be sure, we really don't need that $B$ is bounded below; $B\subseteq E\setminus\{0\}$ is enough, right? The reason why I think that there must be something that I'm missing is [Lemma 2.3.4 in the book of Applebaum](https://books.google.com/books?id=q7eDUjdJxIkC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=%22Lemma+2.3.4+If+A+is+bounded+below,%22&source=bl&ots=AtdtoByOOh&sig=ACfU3U0CjQLfpm-zmIgyR9Jj5g5KKIOdPQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX47Od3-LzAhWGq6QKHRJGA28Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Lemma%202.3.4%20If%20A%20is%20bounded%20below%2C%22&f=true).

Comment: He is imposing the assumption that $B$ ($A$ in the book) is bounded below and I'd be really surprised if he is stressing this assumption when it is not needed at all. Do you see a reason for this assumption?

Comment: (A similar assumption $(0\not\in\overline B)$ can be found on [p. 464 of Medvegyev's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ukIVDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA464&lpg=PA464&dq=%22Assume+that+the+closure+of%22+%22medvegyev%22&source=bl&ots=Yny3l_DGqu&sig=ACfU3U37XuGwu4Uhx14nDlOD8iC8srq9ag&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYh6y68eLzAhWOR_EDHV0_B2cQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Assume%20that%20the%20closure%20of%22%20%22medvegyev%22&f=false); see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4285827/47771)

Comment: @0xbadf00d: If $B$ is closed and $0 \ne B$ then $\Vert B \Vert$ *is* bounded below by a positive number.

Comment: Yes, of course. You got me wrong. That's the point of my question: Why should we need this assumption? I think $0\not\in B$ is enough. I don't see that we need that $B$ is closed or bounded below; neither in this, nor the other question. Meanwhile, I've found this assumption in almost every book on Lévy processes. They say that the point is that "in finite time, $X$ can only have a finite number of large jumps, but an infinite number of small jumps".

Comment: @0xbadf00d: If you define $x(t) = 1- 1/2^n$  on each interval $[1-1/2^{n+1}, 1-1/2^n)$, and $x(t) = 1$ for $t \ge 1$ then $x$ has infinitely many jumps at the points $1-1/2^n$.

Comment: Yes, sure, but *countably* infinite. So, I still don't see the problem.

Comment: Ah, wait a second, I've just noticed that I was confused by the other answer given by quarague claiming that "any compact interval contains only finitely many jumps" and that $0\not\in B$ is all we need. But that's clearly not true, we only that it contains only countably many jumps! So, we need $0\not\in\overline B$ to ensure that it really contains only finitely many jumps! However, this is only needed to apply the argumentation you gave in your answer. Do the desired claims really fail when we've only got $0\not\in B$? In that case, we would still got *countably* many jumps on intervals.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Sorry, I am loosing track of the various options and arguments. – Are you asking if it is true that $0 \ne B$ is sufficient to conclude that there are only countably many jumps?

Comment: No. I'm asking whether $0\not\in B$ is sufficient to conclude $\tau_1>0$ and $\tau_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130816/discussion-between-martin-r-and-0xbadf00d).

Answer (score 0):

So $\Delta x$ measures all the jumps of $x$ and you said you already know that any compact interval contains only finitely many jumps. As $B$ is bounded below, $0 \notin B$, so for any $a,b$ we also have $|t \in [a,b] : x(t) \in B| \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Now $\tau_n$ is just the $n$th jump of a size in $B$. So if there are only finitely many such jumps in any compact interval, it follows that $\tau_n \rightarrow \infty$.

**Edit:** To get $\tau_1>0$ consider say $[a,b]=[0,1]$. If there are no jumps in this interval, than $\tau_1>1$. If there are finitely many, the infimum among them is greater than zero as $\Delta x(0)=0$ by definition.

For the convergence to infinity, for any $N$ there exist only finitely many $n$ with $x(t) \neq 0$ and $t < N$, hence there exists a finite $n(N)$ such that $\tau_{n(N)}>N$ so the limit of the $\tau_n$ has to be infinity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (a) How do we obtain $\tau_1>0$? (b) How exactly are you concluding that $\tau_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$? I mean, clearly, if $I_{n_0}=\emptyset$ for some $n_0\in\mathbb N$, then $I_n=\emptyset$ and hence $\tau_n=\infty$ for all $n\ge n_0$. Are you using this here? (c) As long as your response to (a) and (b) doesn't depend on it, am I right that it is sufficient to assume $0\not\in B$ instead of the stronger assumption that $B$ is bounded below?

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Did you intend to write $t\in[N-1,N]$ (or something like that) in the last paragraph? And please let me ask again: Did we really use that $B$ is bounded below or is $0\not\in B$ all we need?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I meant $t \in [0,N]$, fixed the typo. As I see it, $0 \notin B$ is all we need.

Comment: You wrote that "any compact interval contains only finitely many jumps", but this is not true. We only know that it contains only *countably* many jumps. So, maybe we need that $0\not\in\overline B$ to ensure that it really contains only *finitely* many jumps?! What do you think?