# How do we show that the jumping times $\inf\{t:\Delta X_t\in B\}$ of a Lévy process $X$ are stopping times?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times, levy-processes

[We can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283169/47771) the following: If $E$ is a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ is càdlàg, $B\subseteq E\setminus\{0\}$, $\tau_0:=0$ and $$\tau_n:=\inf\underbrace{\{t>\tau_{n-1}:\Delta x(t)\in B\}}_{=:\:I_n}$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$, then

1. $\tau_1\in(0,\infty]$;
2. If $n\in\mathbb N$, then either $I_n=\emptyset$ and hence $\tau_n=\infty$ or $\tau_n\in I_n$.

Now if $X$ is any $E$-valued càdlàg Lévy process on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0},\operatorname P)$, we can similarly define $I_n$ and $\tau_n$ with $x$ replaced by $X$.

$(\Delta X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is clearly $\mathcal F$-adapted and $(X_{t_1+s}-X_{t_1})_{s\ge0}$ is a Lévy process with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal F_{t_1+s})_{s\ge0}$ with the same distribution as $X$ for all $t_1>0$.

> **Question**: Are we able to show that $\tau_1$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable? Or are we even able to show that $\tau_1$ is measurable with respect to the right-continuous filtration $\mathcal F_{t+}:=\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}\mathcal F_{t+\varepsilon}$? The latter is equivalent to showing that $\{\tau_1<t\}\in\mathcal F_t$ for all $t>0$. Can we show this?

Comment: What is $\Delta X(t)$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $\Delta x(t):=x(t)-x(t-)$ and $x(t-):=\lim_{s\to t-}x(s)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of jumps $\Delta X$ is [progressively measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressively_measurable_process) since it is the difference of two progressively measurable processes. Then, for a measurable subset $B\subseteq E$ the hitting time $\tau_1=\inf\{t>0:\Delta X(t)\in B\}$ is a stopping time according to the [Début theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitting_time#D%C3%A9but_theorem). Note: The theorem assumes that the probability space is complete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping that there would be a more elementary answer which doesn't rely on the Début theorem and hence doesn't require to assume completness (and right-continuity, which I guess you've forgotten to mention) of the filtration.

Comment: What can we say in the canonical setting? Please take a look at the corresponding question I've asked for this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4292571/47771.

Comment: Oh, and might there be a more elementary proof available, if we assume $0\not\in\overline B$?