# Is $\inf\{t>0:\Delta\omega(t)\in B\}$ a stopping time on the canonical path space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stopping-times

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space and $$\Omega:=\{\omega:[0,\infty)\to E\mid\omega\text{ is càdlàg}\}.$$ Moreover, let $$\pi_t:\Omega\to E\;,\;\;\;\omega\mapsto\omega(t)$$ and $$\mathcal F_t:=\sigma(\pi_s,s\le t)$$ for $t\ge0$.

> Let $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ with $0\not\in\overline B$. Are able to show that $$\tau(\omega):=\inf\{t>0:\Delta\omega(t)\in B\}\;\;\;\text{for }\omega\in\Omega$$ is a stopping time with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$?

As usual, $\omega(0-):=0$, $$\omega(t-):=\lim_{s\to t-}\omega(s)$$ and $$\Delta\omega(t):=\omega(t)-\omega(t-)$$ for $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm sorry, I've added the definition.

Comment: So, if you prove $\Delta\omega(t)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable, will that be enough?

Comment: @GEdgar Hm, I'm not sure. Why do you guess that? What we need to show is that $\{\tau\le t\}\in\mathcal F_t$ for all $t\ge0$.

Comment: Because of cadlag, $\sigma(\pi_s,s\le t)$ is the least sigma-algebra such that $\pi_t$ and all $\pi_s$ with  $0\le s<t, s \in \mathbb Q$ are measurable.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, that's clear to me. (But note that we've only got $\mathcal B(\Omega)=\sigma(\pi_t,t\ge0)$ when $E$ is separable; in general, it only holds "$\subseteq$"). But how do you prove the claim by this?

Comment: Since $0\notin\overline{B}$ there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $\lvert b\rvert>\epsilon$ for all $b\in B$. Perhaps you can use the fact that $\lvert\Delta\omega(s)\rvert>\epsilon$ for no more than finitely many $s\in[0,t]$?

Comment: @jakobdt Thank you for your comment. I already thought about that, but this should only give an inclusion ...

Comment: Yes, this is the Début theorem.

Comment: What you are looking for, in the highest possible generality, will be a modified proof of the [Debut theorem](https://almostsuremath.com/2016/11/08/measurable-projection-and-the-debut-theorem/), which is explained and proved here. Also note that there is an introductory section that mentions why some advanced tools are required to answer this question in the most general case. Of course, for the *cadlag* case, there is a much easier proof : that, can be found [here](https://almostsuremath.com/2009/11/15/stopping-times-and-the-debut-theorem/).