# For a cadlag function $f$ prove that $t_{j} = \inf\left\{t>t_{j-1}\mid \left|f(t)-f(t_{j-1})\right|>c\right\}\rightarrow\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\left[0,\infty\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a cadlag function.
Consider the sequence defined as
$$
\begin{cases}
t_0 = 0 \\
t_{j} = \inf\left\{t>t_{j-1}\mid \left|f(t)-f(t_{j-1})\right|>c\right\},\quad j=1,2,\cdots
\end{cases}
$$
where $c>0$ is given.

I need to prove that $t_j\rightarrow+\infty$.

**A (failed) attempt**

We know, by construction, that $t_{j-1}<t_j$ so $\exists \lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}t_j=\sup_jt_j$. Call $C=\sup_jt_j$. If, by absurd, $C<\infty$, then for all $\varepsilon>0$ we will have that, for all $j\geq j_{\varepsilon}$, $C-\varepsilon<t_{j}$, but I cannot figure out here how to use the fact that $f$ has left-limit and is right-continuous.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4279304/42969

Comment: "We know, by construction, that $t_{j-1}<t_j$ so $\exists \lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}t_j=\sup_jt_j$." --- By _construction_ we would only know $t_{j-1} \leq t_j$, which is sufficient for the rest of your current attempt.  It _is_ a theorem that $t_{j-1} < t_j$, but that requires an argument by right-continuity

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if you have a typo.  The title asks about jump times while the $t_j$ definition aren't the commonly defined jump times.  The difference is $|f(t)-f(t_-)| > c$ (for jump times) rather than $|f(t)-f(t_{j-1})| > c$

Comment: @BrianMoehring you are right, sorry, I'll change the title accordingly. You are also right about your first comment, it must be $t_{j-1}\leq t_j$, but how this can help completing the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one needs to adopt the convention $\inf \emptyset = \infty$.
Why? Think of the following simple examples:

- $f$ is constant; or
- $f(t) = \frac{c}{2} \sin t$ for all $t>T$ for some fixed $T\ge 0$.

With that in mind, we need to consider two alternatives:

1. For some $j$, the set defining $t_j$ is empty and as a result, $t_j=t_{j+1} = \dots = \infty$.
2. For all $j$, the set defining $t_j$ is not empty. As noted by [Brian Moehring](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/694754/brian-moehring?tab=topactivity),  right continuity implies that  $(t_j:j\in {\mathbb Z}_+)$ is a strictly increasing sequence. Therefore the sequence has a limit in the extended sense (=may be infinity).  Let's continue with your attempt, and argue by contradiction that the limit is finite.  Since $f$ has limits from the left,  there exists some constant $L\in {\mathbb R}$ such that
   $$(*)\quad \lim_{j\to\infty} f(t_j) = L.$$
   The right continuity of $f$ implies
   $$(**)\quad | f(t_j) - f(t_{j-1})|\ge c.$$

Finally:

$$0<c\overset{(**)}{\le} |f(t_j) - f(t_{j-1})| \overset{\mbox{triangle}}{\le} |f(t_j) - L | + |L- f(t_{j-1})|\overset{(*)}{\underset{j\to\infty} {\to }}0.$$

This is the desired contradition.